# App pool created as v2 starts as v4 and changes to v2 when recycled

Tags: .net, iis, iis-7, msbuild, iis-7.5

I am creating an IIS7.5 app pool in my build script to use .Net2. When initially created it reports its version as 2.0.50727 as expected.

However when I try to attach Visual Studio 2010's debugger to the W3P process running in that app pool, it states that it is running as .Net 4 and I am unable to hit any of my breakpoints.

If I then recycle that app pool and attempt to attach once more, it is now running as .Net2 and I can debug successfully.

Any ideas as to why it runs as .Net 4 when first started would be welcomed. Thanks

Comment: I don't have the answer, but remember .NET 4 (as well as 3.0, 3.5) is built on top of .NET 2, so either way version 2 is loaded.  Not sure why that would affect breakpoints...

Comment: Isn't .Net4 a completely different runtime from 2? That would explain why the v2 and 3.5 code in my app cannot be debugged in a .Net 4 process, I think.

Comment: @Nelson - yep, .NET 4 is not like .NET 3.5/3.0 which is additive to and dependent on .NET 2.0.

Comment: @Kev: Looks like you are both right, though I couldn't find something official on this.  And I was sure it was additive...